# Работа с датами в chart.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js, momentjs

Хочу расположить вдоль на оси x несколько дат в качестве labels с интервалом в один день. Знаю начальную и конечную дату. Можно ли это сделать не прописывая все даты массивом в labels(их может быть очень много), а зная только начальную дату, конечную дату и интервал?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать для оси тип `time`, для этого типа можно задать максимальное и минимальное значение и единицу времени:

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
            min: '2018-03-29',
            max: '2018-04-26',
            unit: 'day'
        }
    }]
}
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/maximzasorin/3tLcon79/

Более подробно в [документации](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html).

Comment: Большое спасибо. Но недостаточно указать просто массив данных в datasets. Так данные не отрисовываются. А нужно как в примере указывать значения по оси y соответствующие им даты по оси x (как в предложенном примере). Но так не удобно. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @lipton_v Могу ошибаться, но по-моему так сделать нельзя.